# What's the difference between file_get_contents a variable and a string?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I have source code :

A.

```
$this->eArticle["product_link"] = 'http://afamily.vn/doi-song/lop-hoc-toa-tau-day-nham-mat-ve-obama-khien-tre-thich-me-20150530074455878.chn';
print file_get_contents($this->eArticle["product_link"]);
```

AND

B.

```
print file_get_contents('http://afamily.vn/doi-song/lop-hoc-toa-tau-day-nham-mat-ve-obama-khien-tre-thich-me-20150530074455878.chn');
```

In A, result return NULL ( `screen haven't text` )

In B, result display website `http://afamily.vn/doi-song/lop-hoc-toa-tau-day-nham-mat-ve-obama-khien-tre-thich-me-20150530074455878.chn`

Why ? How fix ? Thanks !

Comment: `file_get_content`? maybe you're referring to `file_get_contents` _with the **s**_

Comment: Isn't it file_get_contents()? note the "s"

Comment: Hi, thanks all ..error not with the 's' .. i update code :v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am nt quite sure about what you did but

you can try storing it in a variable and function is `file_get_contents()` and not `file_get_content()`, **NOTE** for the **"s"** that you have missed

```
$this->eArticle["product_link"] = 'http://afamily.vn/doi-song/lop-hoc-toa-tau-day-nham-mat-ve-obama-khien-tre-thich-me-20150530074455878.chn';

$website_link = trim($this->eArticle["product_link"]);

echo file_get_contents($website_link);
```

Check out the [Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Comment: Thanks, but i try it and result :( `Warning:  file_get_contents( http://afamily.vn/chuyen-la/co-dau-gay-soc-cho-khach-moi-vi-den-dam-cuoi-bang-quan-tai-20150602104336414.chn ) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: Invalid argument in D:\Work\PHP\xampp\htdocs\crawler\controller\cmd\check.php on line 99`

Comment: In your php.ini file check allow_url_fopen directive, it should be turned on allow_url_fopen = on

Comment: :D default is On .. hi

Comment: ; Whether to allow the treatment of URLs (like http:// or ftp://) as files.
; http://php.net/allow-url-fopen
allow_url_fopen = On

Comment: the problem might be with the link then check for any special characters or whitespace in your link

Comment: Oh, it work, url not trim. When i trim it, it work. Thank u very much. U can update your answer, then i like it :v .. hihi :v

Comment: U are Pro hahahahaha :3

Comment: Thanks :) u help me and some people find this post =)))))